# Android Swipe To Dismiss on PagedList with Realm local Database loses list position

Tags: android, realm, android-livedata

My current Android application is using `<LiveData<PagedList<ModelUI>>` with a Realm local database.

I'm basing my approach on [this](https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/live-paged-lists-architecture-components-and-room-or-realm-268c9299a661) @EpicPanda article.

I'm employing the following Architecture components

```
api "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
api "android.arch.paging:runtime:1.0.1"
```

My datasource classes resemble this:-

```
public abstract class BaseDataSource<T> extends PositionalDataSource<ModelDO> {

    @WorkerThread
    public abstract int countItems();

    @WorkerThread
    public abstract List<ModelDO> loadRange(final int startPosition, final int count);

    @Override
    public final void loadInitial(@NonNull final LoadInitialParams params, @NonNull final LoadInitialCallback<ModelDO> callback) {

        final int totalCount = countItems();

        if (totalCount == 0) {
            callback.onResult(Collections.emptyList(), 0, 0);
            return;
        }

        final int firstLoadPosition = computeInitialLoadPosition(params, totalCount);
        final int firstLoadSize = computeInitialLoadSize(params, firstLoadPosition, totalCount);

        final List<ModelDO> list = loadRange(firstLoadPosition, firstLoadSize);

        if (list != null && list.size() == firstLoadSize) {
            callback.onResult(list, firstLoadPosition, totalCount);
        } else {
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public final void loadRange(@NonNull final LoadRangeParams params, @NonNull final LoadRangeCallback<ModelDO> callback) {
        final List<ModelDO> list = loadRange(params.startPosition, params.loadSize);

        if (list == null) {
            invalidate();
        } else {
            callback.onResult(list);
        }
    }
}
```

and this:-

```
public class ModelDataSource<T> extends BaseDataSource<ModelDO> {

    private static final String TAG = "ModelDataSource";

    private final Realm workerRealm;
    private final RealmResults<ModelDO> liveResults;

    private final RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<ModelDO>> realmChangeListener = results -> {
        if (results.isLoaded()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "REALM DATA CHANGE DETECTED");
            invalidate();
        }
    };

    // WORKER THREAD
    ModelDataSource() {
        Log.i(TAG, "CREATED" + this);
        this.workerRealm = DatabaseController.getRealm();
        this.liveResults = DatabaseController.fetchShortListedResults(this.workerRealm);
        if (!liveResults.isLoaded()) {
            liveResults.load();
        }
        this.liveResults.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
    }

    @WorkerThread
    public int countItems() {
        Log.i(TAG, "COUNTING ITEMS" + this);
        if (workerRealm.isClosed() || !liveResults.isValid()) {
            Log.i("REALM TILED DATA SOURCE", "RESULTS ARE NOT VALID, OR REALM IS CLOSED.");
            return 0;
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "ITEM SIZE [" + liveResults.size() + "]");
        return liveResults.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isInvalid() {
        Log.i(TAG, "REFRESHING REALM." + this);
        workerRealm.refresh();
        return super.isInvalid();
    }

    @WorkerThread
    @Override
    public List<ModelDO> loadRange(int startPosition, int count) {
        Log.i(TAG, "LOAD: " + startPosition + " , " + count + " " + this);
        int countItems = countItems();
        if (countItems == 0) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        final List<ModelDO> list = new ArrayList<>(count);
        for (int i = startPosition; i < startPosition + count && i < countItems; i++) {
            list.add(workerRealm.copyFromRealm(liveResults.get(i)));
        }
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
    }

}
```

My data factory class resembles:-

```
public class ModelDataSourceFactory<T> extends DataSource.Factory<Long, ModelUI> {
    private static final String TAG = "ModelDataSourceFactory";

    @Override
    public DataSource<Long, ModelUI> create() {
        Log.d(TAG, "create() called");
        return new ModelDataSourceFactory().mapByPage(new Function<List<ModelDO>, List<ModelUI>>() {
            @Override
            public List<ModelUI> apply(final List<ModelDO> input) {
                Log.d(TAG, "apply() called with: input = [" + input.size() + "]");
                final List<ModelUI> output = new ArrayList<>();

                for (final ModelDO articleSourceDO : input) {

                    final ModelUI articleSourceUI = constructModelUI(articleSourceDO);
                    output.add(articleSourceUI);
                }
                return output;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My ViewModel repository is a singleton; I configure my pagedList as shown here

```
realmPaginationManager = new PagingManager();
realmPaginationManager.open();

pagedListConfig = (new PagedList.Config.Builder())
        .setEnablePlaceholders(true)
        .setPrefetchDistance(17)
        .setPageSize(20)
        .build();

MY_PAGED_MODELS = new LivePagedListBuilder(new ArticleSourceDataSourceFactory(), pagedListConfig)
        .setFetchExecutor(realmPaginationManager.getFetchExecutor())
        .setInitialLoadKey(0)
        .build();
```

When the list is first displayed it loads 60 items starting from 0 by calling the DataSources `public final void loadInitial(@NonNull final LoadInitialParams params, @NonNull final LoadInitialCallback<ModelDO> callback) {}` method.

The issue I have is that my list must support swipe to dismiss.

When I swipe to dismiss I delete the "swiped" record from the Realm database and my RealmChangeListener invalidates my Datasource as shown e.g.

```
private final RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<ModelDO>> realmChangeListener = results -> {
            if (results.isLoaded()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "REALM DATA CHANGE DETECTED");
                invalidate();
            }
        };
```

What I would expect to happen is that by invalidating the DataStore within my RealmChangeListener this would re trigger the `loadInitial()` method again and I would now see a new List displayed with the swiped item missing.

What actually happens is the following

a). `loadInitial()` is called and loads `firstLoadPosition = 0`, `firstLoadSize = 60`.

b). `loadRange()` is called and loads `startPosition = 60`, `count = 20`

c). `loadRange()` is called and loads `startPosition = 80`, `count = 20`

I now have to page backwards through the list to where I swiped to dismiss and the deleted item has been removed.

Why doesn't the datastore simply call `loadInitial()` and redisplay the top of the list?

Comment: You mean if you swipe away an item, then the list is reloaded completely and scroll position starts back to position 0? That's not how it should be if the page diffing works correctly...

Comment: @EpicPandaForce No, what happens is... I swipe away an item in the list from the first page and the list redisplays, but I am now presented with the list starting at position 61!, when I swiped away an item on the very first page of the list, when I page back to the top the swiped away item has gone and the list contents are correct. I just wonder what mistake I have made that makes the loadRange() method be called twice?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, I found my error... assisted by your "diffing" comment.  My item id's are Long objects however I was comparing them with "==" where I should have been using ".equals()"